# Is this a good design for wrapping asynchronous API calls into a RESTful interface?

Tags: java, rest, spring, asynchronous-programming

I'm working with an API that has many asynchronous calls and handlers. I'd like to extend these with a RESTful interface and endpoints in spring. I'm imagining the usual Controller and Service layers, where the Service probably wraps these async handlers. I've read several articles about CompletableFuture, @Async, and @EnableAsync and eventually got this working, but am not sure I'm doing it 'right' or well-designed. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222044/what-is-a-good-design-pattern-of-interfacing-with-asynchronous-api-in-java/57229623#57229623) does a good job of merging the CompletableFuture and async handlers; at least, the handlers there are similar to mine.

so I have something like this interface:

```
interface AccountHandler {
   void onSuccess(Portfolio result);
   void onError(Throwable error);
}
```

and now this CompletableFuture merged with it:

```
class MyPortfolioCallbackHandler extends CompletableFuture<Portfolio> implements AccountHandler {
   void onSuccess(Portfolio result) {
      super.complete(result);
   }
   void onError(Throwable error) {
      super.completeExceptionally(error);
   }
}
```

The Service looks like this:

```
@Service
public class PortfolioService {

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<Portfolio> getPortfolio() throws Exception {
        MyPortfolioCallbackHandler portfolioHandler = new PortfolioHandler();
        portfolioHandler.getPortfolio();

        return portfolioHandler;
    }
}
```

And the Controller is this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("portfolio")
public class PortfolioController {

    @Autowired
    PortfolioService portfolioService;

    @GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public Portfolio getPortfolio() throws Exception {
        return portfolioService.getPortfolio();
    }
}
```

This actually works, to my surprise, after trying a few things and being confused by the CompletableFuture. But is it a good design, or done 'right'?

Comment: I'm confused by your `PortfolioService.getPortfolio()` definition.  `MyPortfolioCallbackHandler` is a `CompletableFuture` but you return the result of `portfolioHandler.get()`.  Is `PortfolioHandler` a `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<Portfolio>>`?  I'm not sure how else this compiles.

Comment: Yes, `PortfolioHandler extends CompletableFuture<Portfolio>`. I've updated it. Sorry, I started writing this when it wasn't working, then tried a few things, and eventually got it working. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make sense to me.  Your method is declared to return `CompletableFuture<Portfolio>` (as required by the [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html)) but you are returning `portfolioHandler.get()` which should return a `Portfolio`.

Comment: You're right. sorry again. I've edited the service again to only return portfolioHandler. That reflects the current state.

Comment: Without seeing `PortfolioHandler` it's hard to say whether your solution is truly async.  The `portfolioHandler.getPortfolio();` call looks suspicious.  If you are actually doing the work in that call, you are probably not getting the benefit of async execution here.  Can you show more that class, or at least that method?

Comment: I can't show more than that, because that's where it calls the 3rd party API. That API defines these interfaces, which we then implement, and then call their 'controller' methods with these interfaces. And then their controller calls the various methods of the interfaces asynchronously.

Comment: If `portfolioHandler.getPortfolio();` starts the work asynchronously and doesn't block then I don't see anything specifically wrong with this.  I would consider renaming `getPortfolio()` because the connotations of the `get` prefix in Java, though.  You should probably test/debug this to make sure Spring is doing what you expect here.

Answer (score 2):

I'll admit some ignorance regarding Java's implementation of `CompletableFuture<T>`, but in general you may introduce the threat of deadlock due to hidden synchronization calls.  That particular problem is definitely evident in C# `async` and `await` task synchronization.

Hidden within your `portfolioHandler.get()` method is a synchronization call that is waiting for the lock to be released.  Combine that with the unpredictable nature of which thread you will actually be running under in your web server's thread pool and you will always have the risk of blocking the thread that is supposed to be processing the `CompletableFuture`.

*At least I wouldn't attempt this approach with Spring MVC.*

I would look into using **Spring Flux** which is supposed to be Asynchronous by nature.  C# handled the asynchronous thread lock risk by introducing asynchronous handlers.  Matching asynchronous web infrastructure with asynchronous back-end calls should help you avoid that impedance mismatch.

Comment: While `await/async` are fairly easy to use, they are a pretty blunt instrument compared to how Futures work in Java.  "Hidden within your portfolioHandler.get() method is a synchronization call", I'm not sure there's synchronization call there, the concurrency model around the the 'new' Java concurrency is much more sophisticated than that. `Future.get()` will block however.  The OP's code isn't actually doing that, though.  It's actually Spring that is doing the call.  I'm not sure exactly what it's doing but I'd bet it's using a non-blocking approach.